# How to detect built-in functions in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

I'd like to have a Maxima function to detect functions that have already been defined.  This could be called `is_function`, so that `is_function(sin)` and `is_function(exp)` would be true, but `is_function(%pi)` and `is_function(foo)` would be false (assuming that I have not defined `foo`).  Does this exist already?

The manual says

> Some Lisp functions are shadowed in the Maxima package, namely the following ... functionp ...

I'm not sure exactly what this means, but `functionp(sin)` returns `false`, and `functionp(foo)` also returns `false` even if I define `foo(x) := x;`.  Also, `fundef(sin)` and `dispfun(sin)` fail with message `fundef: no such function: sin`, although `fundef(foo)` works if I define `foo(x)` as before.

Comment: Hi Neil, I've updated my answer with a slightly expanded solution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to define functions, and Maxima doesn't really have a way to detect any of them.

UPDATE: An slightly expanded version of the previous solution can now be found at: https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages in the folder robert-dodier/fboundp.

PREVIOUS SOLUTION: Here's an attempt which looks at the Lisp symbol properties to see what's there.

```
/* fboundp.mac -- detect different kinds of functions in Maxima
 * copyright 2020 by Robert Dodier
 * I release this work under terms of the GNU General Public License
 *
 * Examples:
 *
   /* Simplifying function defined in Lisp: */
   fboundp(sin);
   true;
   fboundp_simplifying(sin);
   true;

   /* DEFUN (ordinary argument-evaluating) function defined in Lisp: */
   fboundp(expand);
   true;
   fboundp_ordinary_lisp(expand);
   true;

   /* DEFMSPEC (argument-quoting) function defined in Lisp: */
   fboundp(kill);
   true;
   fboundp_quoting(kill);
   true;

   /* Maxima ordinary function: */
   (kill(foo),
    foo(x) := x,
    fboundp(foo));
   true;
   fboundp_ordinary_maxima(foo);
   true;

   /* Maxima array function: */
   (kill(bar),
    bar[x](y) := x*y,
    fboundp(bar));
   true;
   fboundp_array_function(bar);
   true;

   /* Maxima macro: */
   (kill(baz),
    baz(x) ::= buildq([x], x),
    fboundp(baz));
   true;
   fboundp_maxima_macro(baz);
   true;
 *
 */

fboundp(a) :=
    fboundp_simplifying(a)
 or fboundp_ordinary_lisp(a)
 or fboundp_quoting(a)
 or fboundp_ordinary_maxima(a)
 or fboundp_array_function(a)
 or fboundp_maxima_macro(a);

fboundp_simplifying(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?get(a, ?operators) # false;

fboundp_ordinary_lisp(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?fboundp(a) # false;

fboundp_quoting(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?get(a, ?mfexpr\*) # false;

fboundp_ordinary_maxima(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?mget(a, ?mexpr) # false;

fboundp_array_function(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?mget(a, ?aexpr) # false;

fboundp_maxima_macro(a) :=
  symbolp(a) and ?mget(a, ?mmacro) # false;
```

EDIT: I've made a separate function to test for each kind of function, and I put in a test for `symbolp` to ensure that the property-inspection stuff (`?get` and `?mget`) won't fail.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful as an explanation of the different kinds of definition as well as solving my immediate problem.